# Perl CGI writing to a file concurrently

Tags: apache, perl, concurrency, cgi

Lets say I have the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use CGI ":standard";

...Snippet...

open (FH, '>', "file.txt") or die ("ERROR:$!");
print FH "something";
close(FH);
```

As it it cgi on Apache, this cgi script could be called concurrently.

- How does writing and reading occur when concurrently called?

  - There are no locks or such correct?

What happens if I wanted conditional logic...

1. wait until lsof shows file is clear
2. Read from file
3. concat with text
4. write to file

I am investigating utilizing lsof for setting up synchronous file locking, but do not want to go down bad path. (Might be better off using SQL).

Comment: You'd better use a database, it's been invented already =))

Comment: @Kosh was not sure if "simple task" was "too little" to involve a database.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, you should almost certainly use a database for this.
2. If there's some reason why you really don't want to use a database, then at least use the [file locking mechanisms that already exist](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/flock) and don't invent your own. There are plenty of questions (and answers) about this in [perlfaq5](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq5).

   - [How can I lock a file?](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq5#How-can-I-lock-a-file?)
   - [Why can't I just open(FH, ">file.lock")?](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq5#Why-can%27t-I-just-open(FH,-%22%3Efile.lock%22)?)
   - [I still don't get locking. I just want to increment the number in the file. How can I do this?](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq5#I-still-don%27t-get-locking.-I-just-want-to-increment-the-number-in-the-file.-How-can-I-do-this?)
   - [All I want to do is append a small amount of text to the end of a file. Do I still have to use locking?](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq5#All-I-want-to-do-is-append-a-small-amount-of-text-to-the-end-of-a-file.-Do-I-still-have-to-use-locking?)

Comment: Regarding retrieving FH from concurrent calls, not with file locking, all calls would be writing whatever they could whenever they could (full print statements, partial print statements)?

Comment: Or, write to a single service that then writes to the file (like syslog does). The file locking mechanism isn't a good solution because there's a chance your process will never get a lock. You'll end up writing a program that is mostly about trying to get a lock instead of whatever you are trying to do.

Comment: I think POSIX guarantees atomicity for small writes (<= 4KiB?). So that's another option.